# How can I apply a filter to {%...%}?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter

I need to apply my own filter to this line. How to do it?

```
srcset="{% static 'images/img/shop.png' %}"
```

**filter**

```
@register.filter
def to_retina(value):
    pointer = value[value.rfind('.'):]
    return value[:value.rfind('.')]+'@2x'+pointer
```

It should work

```
srcset="{% static 'images/img/shop@2x.png' %}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First load your template tag library, then use `|` to filter the string inside the tag.

```
{% load your_template_tag_library %}

srcset="{% static 'images/img/shop.png'|to_retina' %}"
```

Comment: It turns out `srcset = "/static/images/img/shop%402x%402x.png"`
And I need `srcset = "/static/images/img/shop@2x.png"`

Comment: There was a typo in my answer - it should have been `shop.png`. The `%40` is the hex encoding of `@` - that should be ok.